# How to write a symbolic summation(symbolic expression) in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-computation

I have an academic license for MATLAB for two months and in this version Simulink is not supported.

My problem is that I want to write a symbolic expression in MATLAB and the debugger shows me that I may need some features of Simulink. The part of code that I want to be converted to a supported format for MATLAB (without using Simulink tools) is the following:

```
syms k
f = theta*X-y;
V = subs(f, k, 1:m);
J = (1/(2*m))*sum(V);
```

How can this be done?

Comment: If `m` is *not* symbolic, and `V` is returned as a vector of length `m`, then `J` should work as-is. Otherwise you should take a look at `symsum`, the symbolic summation function of the Symbolic Math Toolbox (with which you can compute `J` directly, without the auxiliary `V`).

Comment: m is not symbolic, however errors are occurred, I tried to do it through symsum() function, but again it threw me the same error: "To use 'symsum', you might need:
  symsum - Symbolic Math Toolbox"

Comment: Indeed: for symbolic expressions you need the Symbolic Math Toolbox, as native MATLAB was designed for numerical problems. I'm a bit surprised: already `syms` and `subs` should have thrown the same error. Unless those are also present in Simulink... Which is unlikely. I don't know if you're aware of this, but [Simulink](http://www.mathworks.com/products/simulink/) is not for *sym*bolic stuff, but for *simu*lating stuff.

Comment: One way or another(either using the first way of coding or the last one-you  suggested) it throws me this error(that I may need Symbolic Math Toolbox). I am trying to get the add-on but another error occurs(server error). I have the faintest idea of what I have to do to complete my task...

Comment: If you're doing something along the lines [of this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101885-how-do-i-install-additional-toolboxes-into-an-existing-installation-of-matlab) and your licence is valid for Symbolic Math, then neither have I.

Comment: Additionally, `V = subs(f, k, 1:m);` makes no sense (it has no effect) because `f` is not a function of `k`.